# iOS - how to "save as a copy" for annotated photos

Tags: ios

Ive taken a photo on my iPhone (iOS 13.x) and drawn over the photo using iOS's in built annotation tool.

I would like to also have a copy of the photo where i have not drawn over it.

Is it possible to get the annotation tool to save the annotated photo as a duplicate so that i can have both copies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a copy from the Share Sheet *before* you start to annotate the photo.

- Navigate to photo in question
- Activiate Share Sheet
- Scroll down a bit (depending on screen size) and tap on "Duplicate"

Afterwards select "Edit" on one of the photos.